# Current Application Insights Integration Best Practice for IoT Edge Solution

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

What is the best practice to integrate an IoT Edge solution with Application Insights? The current IoT Edge production checklist [1] references a "logspout-loganalytics" project but that does not appear to be officially maintained by Microsoft and hasn't been updated in over a year.

Several older tutorials [2] suggest running the "microsoft/applicationinsights" docker image on the edge to collect and send up logging, but that is now marked as deprecated by Microsoft.

So what is the current best practice recommended by Microsoft to connect an Azure IoT Edge project to App Insights?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/production-checklist

[2] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/docker

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to monitor. Perhaps, the easiest way is to instrument your module code and call Application Insights APIs directly.

The logspout module is specifically for Docker logs emitted to stdout or stderror in the (container) module, so it is somewhat orthogonal for Application Insights.

Comment: Thanks we already have application level logging in place. We are looking to capture the logs from the edge system modules themselves to track any system level faults that arise.

Comment: The logspout module is best option if you want to do a continuous push of edge runtime container logs to log analytics.